# jqGrid - Server side paging - jsonstring - showing incorrect/no data

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am using this code:

```
    var data = {
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', index: 'id', width: "80" },
                    { name: 'Name', index: 'name', width: "300" },
                    { name: 'Value 1', index: 'value1', width: "110" },
                    { name: 'Value 2', index: 'value2', width: "110" },
                ],
                pager: instance.getPager().attr("id"),
                datatype: "jsonstring",
                datastr: {
                    "page": "5",
                    "total": "16",
                    "records": "400",
                    "rows": [
                          {
                           "id": 0,
                           "name": "name0",
                           "value1": 61,
                           "value2": 81
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 1,
                           "name": "name1",
                           "value1": 91,
                           "value2": 48
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 2,
                           "name": "name2",
                           "value1": 65,
                           "value2": 41
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 3,
                           "name": "name3",
                           "value1": 20,
                           "value2": 49
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 4,
                           "name": "name4",
                           "value1": 34,
                           "value2": 91
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 5,
                           "name": "name5",
                           "value1": 80,
                           "value2": 31
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 6,
                           "name": "name6",
                           "value1": 9,
                           "value2": 37
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 7,
                           "name": "name7",
                           "value1": 41,
                           "value2": 14
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 8,
                           "name": "name8",
                           "value1": 10,
                           "value2": 85
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 9,
                           "name": "name9",
                           "value1": 21,
                           "value2": 9
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 10,
                           "name": "name10",
                           "value1": 67,
                           "value2": 55
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 11,
                           "name": "name11",
                           "value1": 50,
                           "value2": 23
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 12,
                           "name": "name12",
                           "value1": 11,
                           "value2": 92
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 13,
                           "name": "name13",
                           "value1": 52,
                           "value2": 54
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 14,
                           "name": "name14",
                           "value1": 55,
                           "value2": 94
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 15,
                           "name": "name15",
                           "value1": 23,
                           "value2": 98
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 16,
                           "name": "name16",
                           "value1": 5,
                           "value2": 69
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 17,
                           "name": "name17",
                           "value1": 19,
                           "value2": 19
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 18,
                           "name": "name18",
                           "value1": 38,
                           "value2": 60
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 19,
                           "name": "name19",
                           "value1": 21,
                           "value2": 78
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 20,
                           "name": "name20",
                           "value1": 22,
                           "value2": 52
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 21,
                           "name": "name21",
                           "value1": 63,
                           "value2": 33
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 22,
                           "name": "name22",
                           "value1": 51,
                           "value2": 13
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 23,
                           "name": "name23",
                           "value1": 51,
                           "value2": 83
                       },
                       {
                           "id": 24,
                           "name": "name24",
                           "value1": 82,
                           "value2": 13
                       }
                   ]
                },
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                rowNum: 25,
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Packages",
                height: "auto",
                ignoreCase: true
    }; 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    instance.getContainer().jqGrid(data);
```

What I am trying to do is return a subset of results from the server (here I have just hard coded them in), and I want to simulate paging by specifying the page and totals and have these appear on the table.

The table is generated and it knows about the rows (it creates rows and my table expands to the correct height), however the cells are blank.

Also the paging numbers are not as I expected the total number of pages and records I was hoping would be 16 and 400 respectively, they aren't, they match the data (1 and 25), so I see 'page 5 of 1' and '101-125 of 25'.

Also if `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },` is missing or set to true then I get an error:

```
TypeError: obj is undefined
```

Is this a bug? Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Does any one know how to fix (can at least reproduce) this problem? Tested in both FF and Chrome.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

One part of the problem is fixed (Kris' answer), I can now see the data in the table. Fixed by changing the name tags in the colModel.

However there are still some outstanding problems:

1. The total page number is still showing as 1 so I see 'Page 5 of 1' I want it to show 'Page 5 of 16'
2. The total number of records are showing as 25 still so I see '101 - 125 of 25' when I want to see '101 - 125 of 400'
3. There is still the error when setting `repeatitems: true`

I assume the first two problems are linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some naming issues in colModel (the names in the colModel should be exactly same as the key in json )

change

```
colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', index: 'id', width: "80" },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'name', width: "300" },
                { name: 'Value 1', index: 'value1', width: "110" },
                { name: 'Value 2', index: 'value2', width: "110" },
            ],
```

to

```
 colModel: [
                            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: "80" },
                            { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: "300" },
                            { name: 'value1', index: 'value1', width: "110" },
                            { name: 'value2', index: 'value2', width: "110" },
                        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your gird definition in your view/html page

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['id', 'name', 'value1', 'value2'],
        colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', index: 'id', width: "80" },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'name', width: "300" },
                { name: 'Value 1', index: 'value1', width: "110" },
                { name: 'Value 2', index: 'value2', width: "110" },
            ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
            rowNum: 25,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Packages",
            height: "auto",
            ignoreCase: true
    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: true });

});

 <table id="list"></table>
 <div id="pager"></div>
```

Then you should define a method that retrieves data from the server, in the above grid we make a call to the url Home/DynamicGridData and here is the definition and the paging logic

```
    public ActionResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var context = new AdvItemsContext();
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows; //this gets you the page size
        int totalRecords = context.db.Count(); //this gets you the totalrecords
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize); //this math get the tota pages avaiable

        var dbdata = context.db.ToList().Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);// this lets you page through the records

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = new[] {
            new {id=0,cell=new[]{"0","name0","61","81"}},
            new {id=1,cell=new[]{"1","name1","91","48"}},
            new {id=2,cell=new[]{"0","name2","65","41"}},
            // all your other values or better yet get this from server
        }
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```